# Проблема прозрачности дочерних окон

Tags: c++, winapi

Все мы знаем, что **стиль `WS_EX_LAYRERED` в Windows 7 и раньше не реализован для окон со стилем `WS_CHILD`**. А мне вот нужны свои контролы (кнопочки и т.д.), их рисую PNGом, да и просто графическими примитивами.

Что делаю я:

1. Если окно располагается на сплошном фоне, то рисую на нём
   прямоугольник цвета фона, а потом, то, что нужно.
2. Иногда делаю не `WS_CHILD`, a `WS_POPUP` и синхронизирую
   перемещение, но это слишком -_-

**Как быть?**

P.S.: XML или что-то из этой оперы для меня не вариант.

Comment: @Abyx, можете предложить библиотеку.Желательно с открытым исходным кодом. А что Вы имеете в виду под "рисовать контролы самому"?

Comment: @Abyx, первый раз вообще о таких сообщениях слышу. Посмотрел в Вижуалке - есть только BS_OWNERDRAW, но это ж не сообщение. WM_DRAWITEM?

Comment: @Abyx дык я не использую listbox`ы. Всё своё - просто дочерние окно. Я же поэтому и задал вопрос, как мне к ним прозрачность применить